# What is the signing context chosen by PolkadotJS API?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension

In the verification of a `schnorrkel` `sr25519` signature, there is a signing context which takes an arbitrary string/bytes.

1. What is the signing context used in the PolkadotJS Extension?
2. Is it something we customize through our own usage of the API?

Answer (score 1):

it seems it's hard-coded to "substrate" in both [`sp-core`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/primitives/core/src/sr25519.rs#L60) and [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/wasm/blob/61624a627b5e8c3359ccb2824346d6e1d6510392/packages/wasm-crypto/src/rs/sr25519.rs#L18)